# How to justify equality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is from a past exam paper and it's been a recurring theme that I'm struggling to 'Justify my answer'.

Let $A = \{2m+1 | m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Which of the following sets $B$, $C$, $D$, are equal to the set $A$? Justify your answer.

$B = \{2n+5 | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$C = \{2s+2 | s \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$D = \{2p-3 | p \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

So two sets are equal if they have the same elements.

$A \subseteq B$: for every $a$, if $a \in A$, then $a \in B$,

$B \subseteq A$: for every $b$, if $b \in B$, then $b \in A$

How would I approach this question? Do I just take a random integer, e.g $m= 5$ and say $(2\cdot5+1) = 11$

And say that if $n = 3$, then $(2\cdot3+5) = 11$ therefore $A$ and $B$ are equal? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Each set contain numbers which are divisible by 2 or not divisible by 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can write them to literally be equal:

\begin{align*}
A=\{2m+1 \mid m \in \mathbb{Z}\} &= \{2m-4+4+1\mid m \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{2(m-2)+5 \mid m \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{2n+5 \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align*}
where in the last step I have done the substitution $n =m-2$. If $m$ ranges over all values in $\mathbb{Z}$, then so does $n=m-2$.

The intuition behind this answer is that $A$ consists of $1+$ every even number, which gives you every odd number. $B$ consists of $5+$ every even number. But adding $5$ to an even number gives an odd number, and it's pretty easy to see you'll get every odd number. So $A$ and $B$ must be the same set.

By the way, $B$ is not the only answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

$$2n+5=(2n+4)+1=2 (n+2)+1=2m+1$$

$$2p-3=(2p-4)+1=2 (p-2)+1=2m+1$$

thus
$$A=B=D\neq C $$

the elements of $C $ are even while the others are odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. However, you must show that for $\textit{all }$ $a\in A$, there is a $b\in B$ such that $a=b$, not just for $a=11$. You could try and check all elements of $A$ one by one, but this will take forever.

I would suggest you choose an $\textit{arbitrary }$ $a\in A$. Then there is an $n\in Z$, such that $a=2n+1$. An element $b\in B$ is of the form $b=2m+5$, for some $m\in Z$. Can you find this $m$ such that $a=b$? If you can, then you have proven $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

If they contain the exact same elements, then any element from from one can be written as an element from the other.

So if $a= 2m + 1 \in A$, can we show that $a = 2p + 5\in B$ for some integer $p$.

$a =2m + 1 = 2p + 5 \implies 2p = 2m - 4 \implies p = m - 2$ so we know $a=2m + 1 =2(m-2) + 5\in B$ so $A\subset B$.

Then we  show that if $b= 2p+5 \in B$ and $b = 2m+1 \in A$ we can solve $p = m+2$ the exact same way so $b = 2p+5= 2(m+1) + 1 \in A$.

So $B \subset A$ so $B= A$.

Do that four times.

.....

But that's the "uninspired" way.   The inspired way is to describe and recognize the sets:

$A = \{2m + 1|m \in Z\}$ then $A$ is the set of all multiples of 2 plus 1; the multiples of 2 are the even integers and when we add 1 to the even integers we get an odd number so $A$ is the set of all odd integers.

$B = \{2p + 5|p \in Z\}$ is the set of all even numbers and if we add 5 or any odd number to an even number we get an odd number.  If we add the same odd number to each of the even numbers we will get the set of all odd numbers.

So it'd be an acceptable answer to write: "$A = B=D = {\text{all odd integers}}; B={\text{all even integers}}".  At least I would accept that.

....

For a harder question say: $A= \{x^2 + 2x + 1|x \in \mathbb Z\}; B=\{y^2 - 4y + 4|y \in \mathbb Z\}$

I would attempt to see if for any $x^2+2x+1 \in A$ there is some $y^2 - 4y + 4\in B$

So I'd try to solve $x^2 + 2x + 1 = y^2 - 4y + 4$

$(x+1)^2 = (y-2)^2$

$x+1 = \pm (y-2)$

$x = -1 \pm (y-2)$

So $x = y-3$ or $x = -y + 1$.  Either one shows me there is a one-to-one correspondence between the members of $A$ and $B$.

So then I would *write* as a solution.  (Yes, in math, we sometimes do work before writing down an answer, consider it a rough draft.)

I'd write:

$A = \{x^2 + 2y+1|x\in \mathbb Z\}$

$= \{(x+1)^2|x\in \mathbb Z\}$

$= \{(y-2)^2|y=x+3\in \mathbb Z\}$

$= \{(x-2)^2|y\in \mathbb Z\}$

$= \{y^2 - 4y + 4 |y\in \mathbb Z\}=B$.